# Hibernate tool gives "Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator.catalog()Ljava/lang/String;"

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

My entity class has a sequence.

```
@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name = "idgen", sequenceName = "PROVIDER_SEQ")
public class Provider extends BaseEntity {
```

Superclass defines idgen. However when I run the Ant task to convert to SQL I get

> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator.catalog()Ljava/lang/String

Am using Hibernate3.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have mixture of JPA 1 and 2 libraries in classpath. As you see from the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/SequenceGenerator.html#catalog%28%29), catalog attribute was added in JPA 2.0. Hibernate 3.0 is rather old (roughly 7 years) and does not implement JPA 2.

Comment: OK so couple of things, 1. I am actually using Hibernate 3.6 (the jar said hibernate3 which made me assume its 3.0). 3.6 apparently does support JPA2. 2. I tried upgrading to hibernate 4 and ran into all sorts of problem (no support for sl4j..it wants to use jboss logging, hibernate ant task to generate schema wont work etc.) So now back to the same 3.6 jar and with the same issue :(

Comment: 3.6 is fine, you do not have to update that. Can you publish whole set of JPA and hibernate libraries you use?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I have - hibernate3.jar, javaassist-3.1.2.GA, javaassist 3.1.5.0.jar, hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.final.jar, hiernate-validator-4.2.0.Final.jar, hiberate-validator-annoation-processor-4.2.0.jar, ojdbc56.jar, jta-1.1.jar  and hibernate-tools.jar

Comment: Likely hibernate3.jar is from rather old version. At the moment newest Hibernate 3 is: http://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/files/hibernate3/3.6.10.Final/

Comment: yup thats the link I used to download as well.